# Function in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do a validation. [I want exact this validation but in angularJS](http://jsfiddle.net/skYqw/2/) I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to write a function which uses if else loop. But i don't know how to write a function. Here which i have tried till now. How to call a function in html page? please anyone can help me with this.

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate","ngMessages"]);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {           
        $scope.name = '';    

        $scope.validate = function(NetProfit) {
        if (NetProfit < 500 || NetProfit > 800)  {
            $scope.greeting = 'Your payment must be between £500 and £800';        
        } 
        else {
            $scope.greeting = '';        
        }
    };
});
```

html code

```
<input ng-model="name2" name="name2" id="NetProfit" type="text">
{{greeting}}
```

Comment: Is `validate` invoked ?

Comment: i am not getting how to invoke it exactly..

Comment: @user5397448 Use a `<form>` and `ng-submit`, or as others have said, `ng-change`.

Comment: Also, don't use `$scope`, use `controller as`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
<input ng-model="name2" name="name2" id="name2id" type="text" ng-change='validate(name2)'>
{{greeting}}
```

`ngChange` documentation is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

But the best way of doing this is to use `$validators` of `ngModelController`

`ngModelController` documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive which will invoke `handler`(expression) every time value is changed..

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = '';
  $scope.validate = function(NetProfit) {
    if (NetProfit < 500 || NetProfit > 800) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Your payment must be between £500 and £800';
    } else {
      $scope.greeting = '';
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='MyApp' ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
  <input ng-model="name2" name="name2" id="NetProfit" type="text" ng-change='validate(name2)'>{{greeting}}
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/p0b5yzcp/)